KeyError: "['Outcome'] not in index"
import seaborn as sb
import researchpy as rp

tips = sb.load_dataset("tips")
tps = tips.copy()
tps.head() 

I have this data set,
rp.summary_cont(tps[["total_bill","tip","size"]])

This code works with summary_cont() but it doesn't work with the summary_cat().
rp.summary_cat(tps[['sex','smoker','day']])  

shows following error:
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-d4a951f5b013> in <module>
----> 1 rp.summary_cat(tps[['sex','smoker','day']])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\researchpy\summary.py in summary_cat(group1, ascending)
    252                 table.reset_index(inplace= True)
    253                 table = table.rename(columns= {index_name: 'Outcome'})
--> 254                 table = table[['Variable', 'Outcome', 'Count', 'Percent']]
    255 
    256             else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2906             if is_iterator(key):
   2907                 key = list(key)
-> 2908             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1, raise_missing=True)[1]
   2909 
   2910         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis, raise_missing)
   1252             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1253 
-> 1254         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
   1255         return keyarr, indexer
   1256 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1302             if raise_missing:
   1303                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1304                 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
   1305 
   1306             # we skip the warning on Categorical

KeyError: "['Outcome'] not in index"

I tried to add another variable because: ['Variable', 'Outcome', 'Count', 'Percent'] in the error note, but it didn't work.

I tested your code with the latest versions (pandas 2.2.2 and researchpy 0.3.6). Here rp.summary_cont() gives a table, but also shows warnings due to researchpy not being compatible with the latest pandas version. And rp.summary_cont() shows a nice table without warning nor errors. You might want to check your versions of pandas and researchpy.

Definetely rp.summary_cont() works well, but rp.summary_cat() is not working but my verison for pandas is not 2.2.2 and i couldn't upgrade it. I guess I should upgrade my conda  first. Thanks for helping, hope I can fix it.
